# Corrupted stack around an SFML variable in VS2012 Debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sfml

I'm using Visual Studio 2012. When compiling in Debug mode the following code results in the error

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'line' was corrupted.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Please ignore this box\n";

  sf::Font font;

  if (!font.loadFromFile("font.ttf"))
    std::cout << "Font not loaded\n";

  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000, 800),
                          "Test Window",
                          sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);

  if (!window.isOpen())
    std::cout << "Problem creating window\n";

  while (window.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event event;

    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
      if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        window.close();
    }

    window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

    sf::RectangleShape line(sf::Vector2f(2, 750));
    line.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    line.setPosition(700, 25);

    window.draw(line);
    window.display();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compiling in Release mode solves the issue but I'd like to know what is causing this and if there is some way to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: In your debug build settings make sure you're linking against the debug version of the SFML library if it's available.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting a red part of [the official tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-vc.php):

> It is important to link to the libraries that match the configuration: "sfml-xxx-d.lib" for Debug, and "sfml-xxx.lib" for Release. A bad mix may result in crashes.